# Prevent application with SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW from obscuring my application

Tags: android, security, user-interface, system-alert-window

Is there any way to assure that my application's window is not obscured by any other application's view using with `SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` permission?

If not, then is there any better way to assure that my app is not obscured by such window apart from obtaining the same permission and refreshing/showing/whatever my own view (of course shown in alert window) every **100ms** or so to keep it visible?

Eventual flickering, in case my application is obscured, is actually a good thing and an indicator to the user that something is wrong.

**EDIT**: It seems that there is no way to do it except from going through KNOX on Samsung or some other proprietary solution for Trusted UI. Accepted answer is enough for my purpose, but it is not an answer for the question asked.

Comment: What are you trying to get? Your app being always on top? Or you're trying to make sure no app is interfering with yours for security reasons (e.g. a rogue app that overlays yours in order to capture a PIN number)?

Comment: Mainly prevent "cloak and dagger" attack, and preventing overlays which could potentially hide important information for application user (and third parties, for example client of the user).

Comment: Also, I'm aware that what I'm looking for is basically TrustedUI, but it seems that available solutions are basically prohibitively expensive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if it's not exactly what you're asking, the closest replacement I know of is:

- Either setting `android:filterTouchesWhenObscured="true"` in your layout (touch events will be filtered and not reach your `View` if they are going through an overlay, regardless is transparent or opaque). See [View#setFilterTouchesWhenObscured(boolean)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setFilterTouchesWhenObscured(boolean)),
- Or overriding `View#onFilterTouchEventForSecurity(android.view.MotionEvent)` and checking for `FLAG_WINDOW_IS_OBSCURED`. See [View#onFilterTouchEventForSecurity(android.view.MotionEvent)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onFilterTouchEventForSecurity(android.view.MotionEvent)).

Later can be implemented like so:

```
override fun onFilterTouchEventForSecurity(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
    if ((event.flags and MotionEvent.FLAG_WINDOW_IS_OBSCURED) == MotionEvent.FLAG_WINDOW_IS_OBSCURED) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Screen overlay detected!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        return false // touch event is cancelled
    }
    return super.onFilterTouchEventForSecurity(event)
}
```

See also the [Security section](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#Security) of View class documentation.

Notice that this functionality is available from API 9+. A workaround for older APIs can be found in this SO Question: [Analogue of android:filterTouchesWhenObscured for API level below 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11054654/analogue-of-androidfiltertoucheswhenobscured-for-api-level-below-9).

Comment: Thanks a lot, is there any way to detect overlay without depending on user interaction? I can add requirement for user to physically touch the screen, but it would be great if it wasn't necessary.

Comment: Apparently this answer promises that, but I couldn't make it really detect if there was an overlay on top of my app, but just the opposite (if my app is able to draw an overlay on top of others) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42429635/how-to-detect-screen-overlay-in-android So, from my tests is not possible, but if you find a way I would love to know. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will keep this one open without accepting your answer for some time, and if no one will provide a better answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks!