# How can I detect screen overlays from other apps?

Tags: android

Is there a way to detect programmatically that another app is drawing over my app?

Or is there a way to block this?

Or is there a way to detect that non-system apps have the SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission?

I have an activity that may not be used when another app is drawing over mine for safety reasons.

Doesn't something like this exist for games etc.?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent application with SYSTEM\_ALERT\_WINDOW from obscuring my application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47177996/prevent-application-with-system-alert-window-from-obscuring-my-application)

Comment: Not completely duplicate. Checking for other apps having the permission is also okay for me.

Comment: then edit the question that way :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use application lifecycle methods, as another app comes in the foreground your will execute onPause and then eventually will go to the background. I have not tried it but this must be the case. Better first go through the application lifecycle methods and then you can play around.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
packageManager.checkPermission(android.Manifest.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW,"com.example.yourpackage")
```

which returns `PERMISSION_GRANTED` or `PERMISSION_DENIED`

The possible solution is to check it by iterating by getting the package name of all the available applications inside the device.

For devices with `targetVersion` less than 23 by default `PERMISSION_GRANTED` will be there.